# installation of vpython using pip in High Sierra

Tags: pip, macos-high-sierra, vpython

I am having issue with installing `vpython` using `pip`. During the installation I get and error as if I do not have `stdio.h`, which I do

```
In file included from _scandir.c:14:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/mf/h7c_zhyd7yl6t7nkgx10j6pw0000gq/T/pip-build-czavCr/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/mf/h7c_zhyd7yl6t7nkgx10j6pw0000gq/T/pip-is5WM1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/mf/h7c_zhyd7yl6t7nkgx10j6pw0000gq/T/pip-build-czavCr/scandir/
```

I am running High Sierra, latest Xcode

Most posts on the web suggest to install the command line tools with 
`xcode-select --install` but I did and I can compile some of my codes just fine. 
Other things I have tried:

1. removing and reinstalling xcode+command line tools
2. remove the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`
3. `CFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++  pip install vpython`
4. `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13 pip install vpython`

but nothing works. I am completely out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to understand the problem above, but I have managed to find two workarounds to get a working version of vpython. Somehow the issue seems to be related to python package I installed from python.org and the pip included.  I removed it and installed instead python2 and python3 using Homebrew and both pip2 and pip3 managed to install successfully the vpython and other modules.

Another alternative, which seems even better is to install Anaconda Python and then use conda to get vphyton.